# Wrong values when pulling data from MariaDB into SQL server using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, mariadb

I have been strugling with this since a couple of days ago...

I hava a MariaDB database which I am pulling data from using ODBC connection from SSIS. The thing is that I have the following on the MariaDB table:

MariaDB query:

```
select 
name, creation, base_grand_total, total_taxes_and_charges, base_total_taxes_and_charges
from _1bd3e0294da19198.`tabSales Order` so
where so.name IN ('SO-01195','SO-01196')
```

[image: MariaDB Results]

Then using a simple DATA FLOW task to copy that data into MS SQL SERVER the query result in the resultinga table in SQL SERVER looks like

SQL Server query:

```
select 
name, creation, base_grand_total, total_taxes_and_charges, base_total_taxes_and_charges
from DestinationSQL
```

[image: SQL Server Results]

As you can see, the last 2 columns has wrong results for the FIRST Sales order

any ideas?

Comment: Are those your whole queries? Are there any other transforms?

Comment: Hello Charlie there is no transformation in between

Comment: Can you try ADO.NET instead of ODBC?

Comment: iT WORKED!!THANKS